# I am trying to implement binary search in C but it is showing runtime error. I have taken the code from internet

Tags: c, arrays, runtime

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a[80], lo = 1, hi, i, mid, object, n;
    printf("enter the size of the array");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("enter the elements in the array in ascending order");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
    printf("enter the element you want to find in the array");
    scanf("%d", &object);
    lo = 0;
    hi = n - 1;
    mid = (lo + hi) / 2;
    while (lo <= hi) {
        if (mid < object) {
            lo = mid + 1;
        }
        if (mid > object) {
            hi = mid - 1;
        }
        if (mid == object) {
            printf("the element %d is found at %d", object, mid);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Come on, please format your code.

Comment: Did author of code mention that your array must be sorted for this to work? Dont just copy paste code, better learn by debugging it.

Comment: how to format it sir. I am a new learner and need help

Comment: The code is running but it's not showing the desired output. i don't know how to debug a code that computer can already compile

Comment: Mr. SMA. Thanks for editing the code but it's still not working. It's ma first question on this site. Thanks for trying to help this newbie.

Comment: `if(mid>object)` --> `else if(a[mid]>object)`

Comment: It's not working @BLUEPIXY i tried it. The output is same. Thanks for ya try

Comment: You need update `mid` at end of while-loop.

Comment: Also `mid = lo + (hi - lo)/2;` is better than `mid=(lo+hi)/2;`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY R Y sure with last comment?

Comment: @FilipKočica I do not know what you to ask. Because I am not fluent in English.

Comment: Ah my bad sorry, in your previous comment `mid = lo + (hi - lo)/2;` wont get middle of the interval.

Comment: Or `mid = (lo + hi) / 2;
    while (lo <= hi) {` --> `while(lo <= hi){
  mid = lo + (hi - lo)/2;`

Comment: @FilipKočica Why do you think so? L + (H - L)/2 ==> L + H/2 - L/2 ==> L/2 + H/2 ==> (L + H)/2

Comment: But why such a complicated ? Never mind you are right.

Comment: @FilipKočica `L + H` may overflow in the `int` range.

Answer (score 3):

The code is broken:

- `mid` is not recomputed at each iteration ;
- you should compare the array element `a[mid]` to `object` instead of its index `mid`.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int a[80], i, n, lo, hi, mid, object;

    printf("Enter the size of the array: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1 || n < 0 || n > 80)
        return 1;
    printf("Enter the elements in the array in ascending order: ");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (scanf("%d", &a[i]) != 1)
            return 1;
    }
    printf("Enter the element you want to find in the array: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &object) != 1)
        return 1;
    lo = 0;
    hi = n;
    while (lo < hi) {
        mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
        if (a[mid] < object) {
            lo = mid + 1;
        } else
        if (a[mid] > object) {
            hi = mid;
        } else {
            printf("the element %d is found at %d\n", object, mid);
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Notes:

- the return values from `scanf()` are checked for successful conversion, avoiding undefined behavior on invalid input.
- `n` must be in range `0` to `80` inclusive.
- the redundant tests are removed.
- `mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;` is better than `mid = (lo + hi) / 2;` as it avoids the potential arithmetic overflow on `lo + hi`. Of course it is a moot point here as `n <= 80` but it is a good precaution to always use safer constructions. The unsafe `(lo + hi) / 2` was a notorious bug in many mainstream implementations that last for decades before sufficiently large arrays exhibited undefined behavior.

Comment: A good answer:  Minor; I like this bi-section technique other than the name "hi" as it is more like "hi plus 1".

Comment: @chux: it is much safer to use the start-included, end-excluded half-open range as it avoids the potential wrap-around problem when computing `n-1` on an empty array were the size and index variables to have the unsigned `size_t` type. I agree it would be more consistent to name the index variables `start` and `end` or `a` and `b` instead of `lo` and `hi`.

Comment: @RudraVatsRV: you can accept this answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.